# Echiveria Spots Disease?

Tags: identification, diseases, leaves, succulents

I got this echiveria a few months ago and its been doing good but ive noticed a few "spots" on it lately and im not sure if this is normal or is it infection, Fungus or disease? one time one of its leaves was being eaten by a slug but ive used bug spray and egg shells to protect it and it currently lives in a plastic greenhouse with a few other succulents. Is it dying or is it doing ok and if theres something wrong what can i do to help it?[image]